How is carousing different from drunkenness in Luke 21:34-36? How should they be interpreted literally and spiritually?

“Be careful, or your hearts will be weighed down with carousing, drunkenness and the anxieties of life, and that day will close on you suddenly like a trap. For it will come on all those who live on the face
of the whole earth. Be always on the watch, and pray that you may be able to escape all that is about to happen, and that you may be able to stand before the Son of Man.”
‭‭Luke‬ ‭21‬:‭34‬-‭36‬ ‭NIV‬‬

In this verse Jesus is warning his disciples about the end times and what we should be on watch for in our own hearts, and so my core questions are:

What is the difference between carousing and drunkenness?

I did some research on this and the word that translates as carousing is:
κραιπάλῃ (kraipalē)
Noun - Dative Feminine Singular
Strong's 2897: Drunken dissipation, surfeiting. Probably from the same as harpazo; properly, a headache from drunkenness, i.e. a debauch
Whereas the word that translates for drunkenness is:
μέθῃ (methē)
Noun - Dative Feminine Singular
Strong's 3178: Deep drinking, drunkenness. Apparently a primary word; an intoxicant, i.e. intoxication

How should these words be interpreted spiritually? Were these words likely only meant as intoxication with wine or are there other kinds of intoxication that Jesus could be talking about too?

Did Jesus only pick these two synonymous words for emphasis? Or is there significance in that one means drunkenness and the other means the headache that you get from drunkenness?


Thank you! I’m really curious about this passage and interested to hear your thoughts!

The operative noun here is κραιπάλη (kraipale) = dissipation, or better, surfeiting = consuming anything to excess and still wanting more.
The Meyer's commentary defines this word as "giddiness from yesterday’s debauch".
Obviously the two words, surfeiting and drunkenness are related and emphasize the bankrupt extent of morality being described as a result of extreme hedonism.  Thus, I would interpret this phrase as a condemnation of hedonism in is multitude forms.
The opposite of this is just as bad - being weighed down with the anxieties of this life.  As an antidote to this, Hebrews advises:

Heb 12:2, 3 - Let us fix our eyes on Jesus, the author and
perfecter of our faith, who for the joy set before Him endured the
cross, scorning its shame, and sat down at the right hand of the
throne of God. Consider Him who endured such hostility from
sinners, so that you will not grow weary and lose heart.


Looking up κραιπάλη (kraipale) in my BDAG (3rd edition, p. 564), it reads "both intoxication, carousing, and its result," which includes "dizziness, staggering, when the head refuses to function." Also included in the definition is "unbridled indulgence in a drinking party."
So, what's "carousing" and how does one go about it?
According to the Cambridge dictionary, to carouse means "To enjoy yourself by drinking alcohol and speaking and laughing loudly in a group of people."
Okay, so to carouse, one needs to assemble a group of people, friends will do, provide them with massive quantities of food along with liquids containing heroic quantities of ethanol, and then have them speak and laugh as loudly as possible. Also have them pretend to enjoy themselves. ;-)
In contrast, private intoxication alone can be accomplished quietly and introspectively at far less cost.
However, the scriptures tell us . . .

18 But if you are led by the Spirit, you are not under the law. 19 Now
the works of the flesh are evident: sexual immorality, impurity,
sensuality, 20 idolatry, sorcery, enmity, strife, jealousy, fits of
anger, rivalries, dissensions, divisions, 21 envy, drunkenness,
orgies, and things like these. I warn you, as I warned you before,
that those who do such things will not inherit the kingdom of God. 22
But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, patience, kindness,
goodness, faithfulness, 23 gentleness, self-control; against such
things there is no law. 24 And those who belong to Christ Jesus have
crucified the flesh with its passions and desires. - Galatians 5:18-24
ESV


3 But immorality or any impurity or greed must not even be named among
you, as is proper among saints; 4 and there must be no filthiness
and silly talk, or coarse jesting, which are not fitting, but rather
giving of thanks. 5 For this you know with certainty, that no immoral
or impure person or covetous man, who is an idolater, has an
inheritance in the kingdom of Christ and God. - Ephesians 5:3-5 NASB

These instructions from the Apostle Paul convey the spiritual implications and alternatives in answer to the question.
